# VueJS router-link ctrl+click link with tag element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

When I use router link without a tag I can ctrl+click this link to open up the link in a new tab. When used with a tag. For example `tag="td"` ctrl+click does not work anymore. The same goes for click-able elements produced with `@click.prevent`

```
<router-link :to="`/contracts/${row.id}`">
  {{ row.type | initials }}
</router-link>
```

This works with ctrl+click

```
<router-link tag="td" :to="`/contracts/${row.id}`">
  {{ row.type | initials }}
</router-link>
<td @click.prevent="someAction()">
  {{ row.type | initials }}
</router-link>
```

This does not work.

What causes this behavior and what can be done about it?

Answer (score 7):

You can wrap `router-link` outside of an `a` tag

```
<router-link tag="td" :to="`/contracts/${row.id}`">
  <a>
  {{ row.type | initials }}
  </a>
</router-link>
```

In this case the `<a>` will be the actual link (and will get the correct href), but the active class will be applied to the outer `<td>`.

[image]
[Reference document](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#applying-active-class-to-outer-element)

Answer (score 1):

In order to direct router activity upon certain events you can access it programmatically. It’s easy to debug and you’ll have a lot of control of inputs and outputs.

```
<td @click.prevent="someAction($event)">xxxx</td>
```

...

```
someAction(event) {
  if (event.ctrlKey === true) {
    // if click + ctrl
    let routeData = this.$router.resolve({path: …});
    window.open(routeData.href, '_blank');
  } else {
    // if just click
    this.$router.push({path: …});
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default tag for `<router-link>` is `<a>` with an `href` attribute, eg

```
<a href="/contracts/123">RowType</a>
```

Your browser knows what to do for a Ctrl+click, ie open the link in a new tab.

For other elements, there is no such default action so nothing happens.